# Booting issues with new PC

Tags: usb-boot

I'm having trouble trying to install win 10 on a new PC I built. Here's my config:

Motherboard: Gigabyte Designare z390 CPU: Intel 9900k

GPU: Asus Rog Strix 2600 Super

Ram: 16MB xpg 3600 DDR4

Empty MM2 drive

I've created a bootable win 10 pro USB key (UEFI) under Mac (that's the only computer I have). I've inserted it into a USB 2.0 at the back of my motherboard on my new PC. The Gigabyte bios sees the drive and I've changed the boot options to the USB. Now, no matter what changes I perform on the Bios (CSM disabled, Other OS selected etc...), when I restart the computer by saving the changes, it doesn't prompt me into windows install, instead it goes back to the Bios. I've tried everything under the sun, even with an external SSD plugged via USB.

Some details: Files are unmounted inside the USB drive.

The drive is formatted ExFat using disk utility (mac).

I've tried plugging into USB 3.0...it doesn't work.

CSM disabled or enabled....same result.

Other OS or windows 8/10....same result.

Does anyone know what is the problem and how can I install windows on my new machine if I only have a Mac in my possession.

Comment: Windows 10 needs to be licensed. Most users have a previous version of Windows, and can do a free in-place upgrade. You need licensed installation media for a fresh install. Try installing Linux instead, e.g. Ubuntu, to see if the system is working.

Comment: The win10 iso file is downloaded straight from Microsoft. I have it installed on a USB drive as well as on a SSD (connected via USB). None of them boot windows.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik what? Microsoft's publicly available ISO's are well suited for fresh installs, you just have to enter a license key during setup or activate later within windows. They aren't reinstall-only at all.

Comment: I agree with @MMM. I have done fresh installs with the ISOs from Microsoft. This sounds more like an issue with the configuration.

Comment: @BitStarter, how did you build the bootable USB drive? It sounds like that while the motherboard can see it, it is likely missing the needed boot files on the drive.

Comment: @BitStarter Secure Boot must be _enabled_, with Legacy [CSM] mode _disabled_, in the UEFI firmware.  If the InstallUSB still does not boot afterwards, the installUSB wasn't properly configured for EFI boot for a UEFI install when it was created (it should be formatted NTFS for a UEFI install).  Correct the first, or both, and the installer will load. _Just an FYI, the install ISO should have been downloaded directly from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)_

Answer (score 0):

I called gigabyte, the manufacturer of my mobo. They helped me figure out what was the problem. Basically, none of the functions of the motherboard should be changed in order to install a new OS. Not even the boot sequence. The reason nothing worked is because you can’t create a viable boot drive within Mac OS. It simply doesn’t work no matter what you do or how you format the drive. You gotta have a Windows PC to create a working bootable drive using Microsoft media tool and this little program will create a bootable system into a USB and then without changing anything on your motherboard, let your new pc boot normally without changing the boot sequence in the bios.

The big news is that not only you don’t have to mess up with the bios but you can even use a portable ssd and also use a USB 3.0 port.
Why it’s big news: it’s because most blogs talk about changing a bunch of things in the bios, using USB 2.0 and fat32 usb drive. I was told that the boot system in the motherboard doesn’t care about the format type or the speed of the connection because these things are on the software level while the booting system is on the hardware level. Thanks gigabyte for the enlightenment. Problem solved.

Comment: "under Mac"..., was this a trick question? Very good post! Why didn't we see this?